# Plugin "react" was conflicted with eslint

Tags: reactjs, eslint, package.json

***Этот вопрос сразу можно закрыть как дубликат, так как вопрос с точно таким же заголовком существует, но там нет ответа, может помогут тут***

при `npm start` после компиляции сразу вылетает ошибка с полным текстом:

```
Failed to compile.

[eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » D:\Backend\code\interactive\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » D:\Backend\Code\interactive\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
ERROR in [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » D:\Backend\code\interactive\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » D:\Backend\Code\interactive\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

Из интернета вычитал одно из решение в **package.json** нажимать `ctrl + s`, но при любом изменении в **index.jsx** или перезагрузке страницы эта ошибка вылезает снова.

Пробовал также откатить до 6й версии:

`> yarn remove eslint-config-react-app`

`> yarn add eslint-config-react-app@6`

Не сработало.

Пытался обновить eslint - `npm update eslint` - тоже не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Не самый лучший ответ, но другого решения я не нашел. Просто создал в корне другую директорию , перенес туда проекты, и все работает нормально